# Android: A Slight Change in Accelerometer Sensor calls an activity many times.

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer, text-to-speech

I'm developing a simple android game. I'm new to android and now I got stuck into this logical error. 
The game only uses accelerometerSensor and Text to Speech. A voice tells you to perform some action (e.g. tilting the device up, down, left, right etc.) And if you do it, your score will be incremented (Now I'm done with all this part.) and if not, you are asked to try again.

But the problem is of making the game challenging. To make it challenging, I want that if the user tilts the device in wrong direction he looses it and the game starts again with the score of 0.

As I'm using accelerometer sensor. So a slight change in the sensor calls onSensorChanged many times.

Think of it like this, the user is playing the game, and is asked to perform some action e.g. "Up". As he is moving the device upwards, in the mean time onSensorChanged is called many times and is reporting the if condition as wrong so it goes to the else block, which say Start another activity (the try again page). Instead of starting the activity only once, it starts it too many times until the condition is correct. 
What I want is that if the user does it wrong, he is asked to try again in another activity only once. Not hundred times.

The onSensorChanged and onAccelerometerChanged looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        onAccelerometerChanged(event);
    }

}

private void onAccelerometerChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, Loose.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    int x = (int) event.values[0];
    int y = (int) event.values[1];
    int z = (int) event.values[2];

    mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
    mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x + y * y + z * z));
    float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
    mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter

    if (write.getText() == arr[0]) {
        // Waiter.run();
        if (y == 9) { // for Y aka Up
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccelerometerChanged for Y Called!");
            powerUp.start();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Up! Very Good!",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            status.setText("Up! Very Good!");
            scoreInt += 1;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            BeginPlaying();
        }

        else {
            // powerDown.start();
            // scoreInt -= 1;
            // mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            // score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    else if (write.getText() == arr[1]) {
        // Waiter.run();
        if (y == -9) { // for -Y aka Down
            powerUp.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccelerometerChanged for -Y Called!");
            scoreInt += 1;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            status.setText("Down! Very Good!");
            BeginPlaying();
        }

        else {
            // powerDown.start();
            // scoreInt -= 1;
            // score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            // mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
             startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

    else if (write.getText() == arr[2]) {
        // Waiter.run();
        if (x == -9) { // for -X aka Left
            powerUp.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccelerometerChanged for -X Called!");

            scoreInt += 1;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            status.setText("NegSide! Very Good!");
            BeginPlaying();
        } else {
            // powerDown.start();
            // scoreInt -= 1;
            // score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            // mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    else if (write.getText() == arr[3]) {
        // Waiter.run();
        if (x == 9) { // for X aka Right
            powerUp.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccelerometerChanged for X Called!");
            scoreInt += 1;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            status.setText("Side! Very Good!");
            BeginPlaying();
        }

        else {
            // powerDown.start();
            // scoreInt -= 1;
            // score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            // mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    else if (write.getText() == arr[4]) {
        // Waiter.run();
        if (z == -9) { // for Back 
            powerUp.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccelerometerChanged for Upside Down Called!");

            scoreInt += 1;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            status.setText("Upside Down! Very Good!");
            BeginPlaying();
        }

        else {

            // powerDown.start();
            // scoreInt -= 1;
            // score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            // mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    else if (write.getText() == arr[5]) {
        // Waiter.run();
        if (z == 9) { // for Front aka Right Side Up
            powerUp.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccelerometerChanged for Z Called!");

            scoreInt += 1;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            status.setText("Front! Very Good!");
            BeginPlaying();
        }

        else {

            // powerDown.start();
            // scoreInt -= 1;
            // score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            // mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    else if (write.getText() == arr[6]) { // tap
        // Waiter.run();
        layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (write.getText() == arr[6]) {
                    powerUp.start();
                    scoreInt += 1;
                    score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
                    status.setText("Tap! Very Good!");
                    BeginPlaying();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    else if (write.getText() == arr[7]) {
        // Waiter.run();
        if (mAccel > 2) { // for Shake
            powerUp.start();

            Log.d(TAG, "onAccelerometerChanged for Shake Called!");

            status.setText("Shake! Very Good!");
            scoreInt += 1;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            BeginPlaying();
        }

        else {
            // powerDown.start();
            // scoreInt -= 1;
            // score.setText(String.valueOf(scoreInt));
            // mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

The calling function BeginPlaying() is:

```
private void BeginPlaying() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (scoreInt > 10) {
        ttobj.setSpeechRate(2);
    }
    if (scoreInt > 18) {
        ttobj.setSpeechRate(3);
    }
    if (scoreInt > 30) {
        SharedPreferences scoreValues = getSharedPreferences(
                "MyScoreValues", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = scoreValues.edit();
        editor.putString("SValue", score.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    // powerUp.start();
    randSelect = randGen.nextInt(arr.length);
    write.startAnimation(animPushin);
    write.setText(arr[randSelect]);
    speakTextSensor();

    // SystemClock.sleep(2000);

}
```

The arr[] is the array that contains the actions to be spoken and displayed on screen.

The speakTextSensor() is:

```
public void speakTextSensor() {
    String toSpeak = write.getText().toString();
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    // .show();
    ttobj.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

}
```

I've used unRegisterListener, SystemClock.sleep(), Handlers.. But they don't seem to solve the issue.

It would be really kind and helpful if someone solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand how an accelerometer works.  Imageine there was a pliable metal spring made of thin foil on the outside of your phone.  When you move it away, the base of the spring moves first so the spring expands a little.  When you move it twoards you, it contracts.  When it goes back to normal (from either direction) it bounces a bit, with each bounce (usually) shorter than the previous one until its imperceptable.  That's basically an accelerometer.  Notice that means if you move it forwards then stop that this will happen twice (once for start and once for stopping) and the two waveforms can have positive and negative interference.

(This isn't quite how a modern accelereometer works and its incomplete, but its a simplification to explain it)

The accelerometer sensor gives you the raw data of what the accelerometer currently reads.  It doesn't account for the bouncing, or for the time it takes to go back to normal, or anything like that.  You have to.  The processing of that data is called DSP (digital signal processing) and learning how to do it can take years.

In your particular case, there might be an easy out.  Simply make it so that when you detect an event strong enough for you to trigger, debounce.  Save the time that it occurs at, and don't process any more events for 1 second (or whatever length of time you feel appropriate).  That will fix your current problem.

Here's two other major issues with your code as freebies:

1)Your z code will either go off way too often or all the time.  Thats because z is almost always 9 or 10, due to gravity.  Unless the phone is held at an angle of course, in which case it will be lower and some of the others will be higher than 0 when held still.

2)If you were using the value 9 because it seemed to work well when the device was put completely on its side (due to gravity), don't.  Some devices will actually read 10 due to gravity, these devices aren't well callibrated (mine reads 10.23 by default).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me a little. I was unaware of the fact the devices aren't well calibrated. As far as the Z code is concerned, well, according to this game, the device is not always in a fixed Z position, user is always following the orders and tilting it accordingly. So it only executes the Z code only if the condition  is true.

Comment: I don't know how to achieve these steps through code. Like not processing any more event for the specified time, debouncing etc.

Comment: Debouncing-  when you see a motion event, you save the timestamp.  When you get the next accelrometer call, check and see how long ago that timestamp is.  If it isn't long enough ago (say 1 second ago for example), immediately return instead of processing the data.  That will probably be enough for your immediate need.  If you end up needing advanced techniques down the line you're going to need to do some research or hire someone.